# How can I increase the stack size with runhaskell?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm writing some disposable Haskell scripts to solve some of the [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) problems. I don't really want to have to compile them because of the number of changes I'm constantly having to make, but in a few cases I've found that I've run out of stack space.

The documentation for `runhaskell` says that the following syntax should increase the stack space:

```
runhaskell +RTS -K5M -RTS Script.hs
```

This never, ever works (in any permutation I've tried). The stack size always remains 8,388,608. This is maddening, and I haven't found much help on Google.

Any suggestions? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using GHC.  Chapter 4 of the User's Guide of the newly released 6.10.1 says:

> The only runghc flag currently is -f
>   /path/to/ghc, which tells runghc which
>   GHC to use to run the program.

I don't see a bug logged at http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc .  Seems pretty lame to me.  I'd suggest asking on irc #ghc, or the cvs-ghc mailing list.

Of the other Haskell compilers/interpreters, only nhc98 seems allow you to set the max stack size.  Depending on your OS, nhc98 could be an option.

Comment: it's a runtime-system (RTS) option, see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/431989/214446)

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing the same thing (Project Euler) and have been using ghc. The trick (thanks #haskell!) is to tell the *executable* to have more stack size rather than the *compiler*.

```
$ ghc -O2 -o 23 23.hs
$ ./23 +RTS -K128M
```

Answer (score 1):

Just compile it.

Problem123.hs:

```
module Main where
main = do
    print solution
solution = ...
```

Short and sweet command line:

```
ghc --make -O3 Problem123.hs
./Problem123
```

Final note: I'm not sure I would call them "scripts".

Comment: Yeah, It's easy enough to compile using --make. However, it's even easier to hit R in TextMate on OS X and have the file executed with runhaskell. When you're hacking away and constantly changing things, it's just easier.

Comment: Scripting has always been one of the design goals of Haskell, and calling programs scripts is fairly common, for example:
  http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.functional/browse_thread/thread/5a6df7d9b550346f?hl=en